# Wakawaka Wiki Markup

Tags: django, wiki, markup

I have installed the Wakawaka wiki plugin in my django app. However, I have not been able to figure out the markup syntax for the wakawaka wiki. Googling about it also wasn't much helpful. Which markup syntax does it use?

Answer (score 1):

The wakawaka app is very light weight.. It seems intentional.

It does not support mark up.